# spring saveOrUpdate

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am trying to build a web application using Spring and Hibernate. I have an object which is being saved in the database (hibernateTemplate.SaveOrUpdate method) with an id generated by hibernate. My question is: how can I get the automatically generated id ?

Comment: it should be set on the entity like Bozho said

Comment: No, it's generated automatically. I solved the problem,thanks for your reply.

Comment: @!Alexandra yes, it is generated and set on your entity. So after the saveOrUpdate you should be able to retrieve it. I'm not entirely sure if this particular method behaves like that though

Answer (score 0):

Use [save](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate/HibernateTemplate.html) to get the generated key back.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to do this with SaveOrUpdate but I am shure that I won't update so this works for me.